# Selenium C# - Dispose SignIn Dialog ( Chrome )

Tags: c#, selenium, authentication, dialog

I have an issue where when I land on the first page in a website, a authorization pop up comes up.

[image]

I need to either hit the enter button or do a page refresh ( which closes the pop up ) ..
Can any one please help me in disposing the pop up. 
I tried 
Driver.Navigate().Refresh() when the pop up. 
This does not refresh the page ( which will result in closing the pop up )

Is there any other way to close the pop up apart from using AutoIT dll. [image]

Thanks a lot for your help on this

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation how to handle the alerts in C#.
[IAlert Interface](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_IAlert.htm)

Try the below logic to handle your scenario.

```
IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
alert.Dismiss();
```

Make sure to switch back to parent window once this done.

Comment: Have you tried the below chrome options, by any chance. `options.UnhandledPromptBehavior = UnhandledPromptBehavior.Dismiss;` or `options.AddArguments("--disable-notifications");`